# iTextSharp: border is not showing properly on inner table's td element

Tags: html, css, itext

[image]

I want to add border on top on inner table td element. But it's showing just on corners not on whole top. here's the code.

```
<table style="width:100%; font-size:11px; repeat-header:yes;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> 
     <tr style="page-break-before:always; background-color:#fff">
         <td colspan="5" style="background-color:#ffffff; background:#ffffff;">
             <table class="page-break-details" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse; font-size:14px;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                 <tr style="margin-top:2px;">
                     <td colspan="5" style="text-align:center; margin-top:2px; border-top:5px solid #000;">
                         <h2> Report </h2>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

see the *Report* td element. it's just showing border on corners not on whole td

Comment: can you provide fiddle for your code

Comment: yes plz provide jsfiddle link or proper code snippet. thanks

Comment: on jsfiddle with my code it's working fine. but while working with itexsharp it's generating corner borders

Comment: is there any solution regarding this issue.?

Comment: Your itextsharp related code is missing. In particular do you use the `HTMLWorker`, the `XMLWorker`, or do you actually use itext 7 with its html-to-pdf module?

Comment: as I am using XMLWorker:
    

    var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
    xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, inCssFile: null);

Comment: Can anybody tell me about answer of this question.?